# Change color of button when liking a post using SignalR

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, ng-class, signalr.client

I have created an app with a list of posts and a user can like/unlike a post. For the like functionality I've used SignalR and everything works fine, but I want to change the color of the like button if the logged user has already liked a post, so that he knows which posts he has liked. If a user has not liked a post, the like button will be grey, otherwise, it will be orange. I've tried doing it like this, using ngClass based on a boolean isActive:

```
<button (click)="liked(post)" class="btn liked mr-5">Like <em [ngClass]="[isActive ? 'my-color' : 'active-color']" class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></em> {{post?.likes.length}}</button>
```

```
.my-color {
  color: grey;
}

.active-color {
  color: #e08e23;
}
```

```
export class PostCardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() post: Post;
  isActive = false;

 constructor(private postService: PostsService) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postLiked();

    this.likesSubscription = this.postService.likeMessageReceive.subscribe(result =>{
      
        if ( result.postId ===  this.post.id) {
            this.post = result.numOfLikes;
        }
  })

    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.postId = params['id'];
    });
}

postLiked() {
    const user: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const id = this.getDecodedToken(user.token).nameid;
    var checkLike = this.post.likes.filter(like => (like.userId === parseInt(id)));
    console.log(checkLike);
    if(checkLike.length === 0) {
      this.isActive = true;
    }
    return this.isActive;
  }

  liked(post: Post) {
    const user: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const id = this.getDecodedToken(user.token).nameid;
    
    this.postService.setLike(parseInt(id), post.id)
    .then(() => {
      this.postLiked();
    });
  }
}
```

The like functionality built with SignalR looks like this:

```
 private hubConnection: HubConnection;
 likeMessageReceive: EventEmitter<{ numOfLikes: Post, postId: number, userId: number }> = new EventEmitter<{ numOfLikes:Post, postId: number, userId: number }>();


 connectHubs(user: User) { 
      this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.hubUrl + 'like', { accessTokenFactory: () => user.token, 
      skipNegotiation: true, transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets })
      .build();
  
      return  this.hubConnection.start()
                 .then(() => {
                     this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (numOfLikes, postId, userId) => {
                      user.id = userId;
                       this.likeMessageReceive.emit({ numOfLikes, postId, userId });
                     });
                 })
                 .catch(error => console.log(error)); 
  }
  
  setLike(userId: number, postId: number) {
     return this.hubConnection.invoke('SetLike', userId, postId);
  }
```

Backend:

```
        public async Task SetLike(int userId, int postId)
        {
            Like l = new Like();

            Like temp = _context.Likes.Where(x => x.PostId == postId && x.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();

            if(temp != null)
            {
                _context.Likes.Remove(temp);
            } else
            {

                l.UserId = userId;
                l.PostId = postId; 

                _context.Likes.Add(l);

            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            var post = await _postRepository.GetPostAsync(postId);

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", post, postId, userId);

        }
```

When I am unliking a post, the button turns from orange to grey instantly and works as desired. However, the other way around, if I'm liking a post, the button only turns from grey to orange after refreshing the page, not instantly. Why is that?

Comment: How `checkLike`/`isActive` log looks like? Anyway I assume wrapping `this.postLiked();` with [ngZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) will help as the callback, after a `setLike` promise is resolved, might not be picked up by Angular for change detection. If the `isActive` is logs is updated everytime with `false`, `true`, ... but on the UI printing the `{{ isActive }}` will not be in sync, then try ngZone.

Comment: isActive either returns true/false and checkLike looks like this `[]` if the current user has not like a post and something like this if he/she liked it `[info about user]`. But now I'm see that checkLike is always empty, even if a user has liked a post, maybe this is the problem. I have not worked with ngZone so far, you mean something like this? `this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.postLiked(() => { isActive = ...
      });
    });` I think I'm calling the methods wrong, but I don't see the problem.

Comment: If this is a problem about actually setting the proper value for `isActive`, then we probably cannot help without other details. Although the line `this.post.likes.length = result.numOfLikes;` also doesn't look right, unless `likes` isn't an array and `length` isn't the length of it. As for ngZone, You had an [example](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#example) of usage in the docs. So `then(() => this.ngZone.run(() => this.postLiked()))`.

Comment: I figured the problem, but I don't know why it happens. When I'm unliking a post everything works fine, the number of likes is decremented and the like object is removed from the database. However, when I like a post, the number of likes is incremented, but the like is not set in the database and I get an empty object like this: `(2) [{…}, empty]`. Why is that? I aslo posted my backend code.

Comment: What also bothers me is when and how You are adding likes You are filtering upon. Because if You are doing it on hub's `ReceiveMessage`, it might be already too late (after setting `isActive `). Probably the better place to calculate `isActive` would be `likesSubscription ` then `setLike`. Or just setting `this.isActive = false;` instead of calling `this.postLiked()`. You know that this this is You whom liked the post anyway, so why bother calculating this.

Comment: `(2) [{…}, empty]` as I said, I don't like the `this.post.likes.length = result.numOfLikes` line. What You receive confirms it. And I also may rephrase the `unless likes isn't an array and length isn't the length of it` - if this is the array, You probably wanted to do something else with it, not just increasing its size but actually add a like object there. `is not set in the database` - any error on SaveChanges? Does it return 1, 0? Maybe it is not removed and PK is duplicated? Hard to tell.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm actually sending the old post in onInit, just with an increased number of likes, without actually adding the like to it. I want to send the post and then get the number of likes based on the post, without hardcodeing the number of likes. I have no errors on SaveChanges. The like is added to the database, but I can only see this after a refresh

Comment: Ok, solved the problem with the number of likes. I emitted the post instead of the like number and I'm using this.post.likes.length only in the html and the error went away. But the color of the button behaves the same. It works at unlike, but doesn't work on like. I have updated my code.

Comment: So two solutions here. Either start also sendig added like with data who added that or change the code in the way You do not need that (so assume that if You are calling `postLiked()`, You know it was You who liked it, so You can set `isActive` to `false` without needing to do any calculations). You said that on refresh it is fine, so on refresh You are getting the whole list of likes probably. With the current solution `[not Your like, null, null, ..., null]` will always result in `isActive` to be `true`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what was happening, but now I'm getting the correct list of likes, without nulls.

Comment: Well yes, the problem is now indeed with the isActive, but how can I send the correct value at all times? I find it weird that it works in one case but not in the other

Comment: Ok, solved something. Now the button changes color the correct way, only it works after I press it one time. The first time does not work, but from the second press it works fine. OnInit gets the colors wrong when loading the page. The liked posts appear grey and the other ones appear orange, but as I said, if I press the button once it starts working fine.